# Select values with multiple limit

Tags: mysql

I want to do a mysql query with multiple patterns in the same column. But per pattern I only want the oldest entry

I would like to search for the oldest entry of each pattern (test1, test2, test3, test4)

if i search individually i use this:

```
SELECT * FROM database WHERE name LIKE 'test1' ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1
```

my pattern examples are :

```
test1
test2
test3
test4
```

the sorting should then be from new to old

Comment: Do you want exact or partial matches?

Comment: a exact match from pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to search for exact matches of `'test1'`, `'test2'`, `'test3'` and `'test4'` then you can use the operator `IN` (no need for `LIKE`).
With `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t.* FROM tablename t 
WHERE t.name IN ('test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4') 
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM tablename
  WHERE name = t.name AND time > t.time
);
```

With a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT t.* FROM tablename t 
WHERE t.name IN ('test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4') 
AND t.time = (SELECT MAX(time) FROM tablename WHERE name = t.name);
```